# How can I "fail" a build without halting in ant?

Tags: java, ant, build

Hi : I hava an ANT build which fails, and halts on failure.  I want the build to (rather than halting on failure of a single unit test), finish running ALL unit tests, so that I can know which ones passed/failed.

Then (of course), I want the build to **ultimately fail**, printing out the number of failed tests.

Oddly, it appears that "haltonfailure", does more then "halt" the build : it actually changes the Success/Failure outcome as interpretted by Jenkins !

I would like to , if possible, use the custom "fail" tag to make this clear in my build script, i.e. something like :

```
    <fail message="Some test(s) failed !">
      <condition>
         <not>
          <testFailures>0</testFailures>
         </not>
      </condition>  </fail>
```

Comment: thats odd indeed. I have been using haltonfailure="no" without any problems. can you please post a snippet of your ant file?

Comment: normally `haltonfailure` is set to `off` by default for JUnit tests, have you changed it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The failureproperty attribute on the Junit task and a conditional fail works well.  I use it for generating the junit html reports even if the tests fail.

```
<junit failureproperty="junit.failed" haltonfailure="no">
   <!--- stuff -->
</junit>
<!-- Generate junit reports, pmd, coverage, etc -->
<fail if="junit.failed" message="Failed tests"/>
```

Comment: hmm i also just learned that an error is considered a failure.... meaning sometimes a test will still halt, even if this is set to "no" .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936140/ant-junit-failure-triggers-a-haltonfailure

Comment: Can also do this with TestNG.