# Ant : Junit failure triggers a haltonfailure

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have found that the following :

```
<junit haltonfailure="no" haltonerror="no" >
   <!-- some tests guaranteed to call Assert.fail(); --> 
</junit>
```

Will not prematurely halt (all tests will run).

HOWEVER ...... The following

```
<junit haltonfailure="no" haltonerror="yes" >
```

Will fail after the FIRST failed test.  Note that in this case, I'm guaranteeing that the test is failing via Assert.fail();

**This, I am assuming that either**

1) Ant considers an ERROR to be a subclass of a FAILURE. or

2) There is a oddity in the way ant percieves failures - that is, failures are treated (erroneously) as errors when deciding to halt.

My Question : Why would ant would halt on a test failure (even when explicitly configured with haltonfailure="no").  Any thoughts could be very enlightening ! Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I now realize that this is clearly an RTFM question which is covered in the ant http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html (see correct answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from junit ant task [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html):

> haltonfailure: Stop the build process if a test fails (errors are considered failures as well).

So the answer is: ant junit considers failures as errors, hence the stop of the build